# How to overload method for labels in C#

Tags: c#, methods, overloading

I'm new to C# and programming in general, so a detailed explanation would be appreciated for better understanding.

I have over 50 labels that I need to update as my program progresses.  I want a method with overload string that will update these labels.

For example, I have:

```
label1.Text = "Waiting";
label2.Text = "Waiting";
label3.Text = "waiting";
```

I want to update these labels in a method.  I have something like this:

```
private void updateStatus(string some_program, string label_number)
{
  if (some_program== true)
  { label_number.Text = "Completed"; }
  else
  { label_number.Text = "Failed"; }
}
```

When I run the method, I want it to look like this:

```
updateStatus("file1", label2);
```

However, I keep getting errors on this.  I know my logic is off because of my overload method, but I'm not sure how to get a label to update it's text in a method call.

Comment: Just in general, if your question is asking how to fix an error, it greatly increases your chance of getting help if you post what the error is. (Also, yes, strings don't have a Text property.)

Comment: Use the proper type, your "label_number" argument is a Label, not a string.  As the compiler *tells you*.

Comment: Rather than creating 50 labels, you should look into arrays. If you don't, you will need to use reflection to select a label using a string.

Comment: in your function argument you are passing some_program as a string , but in your code if (some_program== true) , you are comparing with boolean value. That's the error dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `updateStatus("file1", label2);` expects that you're passing in a Label. However, the function you defined, `void updateStatus(string some_program, string label_number)`, states that it expects two parameters, both of them strings. It is clear from the fact that you're attempting to modify the Text property of the label_number parameter, that you actually meant to define the function as:

```
private void updateStatus(string some_program, Label label_number)
{
  if (some_program== true)
  { label_number.Text = "Completed"; }
  else
  { label_number.Text = "Failed"; }
}
```

Of course, that still doesn't compile, because you're also treating `some_program`, which is defined as a string, as if it were a boolean. What does it mean for a string (specifically, in your example, the string "file1") to be true or false? Really, you should read the errors the compiler is giving you - it's probably complaining that it can't convert a string to a bool, and that string doesn't have a property "Text", both of which are clearly true.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Overloading with Label and the name.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `updateStatus()` method takes a string for the both parameters, but you're passing it a `Label` for the 2nd.

The other problem is that `some_program` is type `string`, but you're treating it like a `bool`. You haven't given enough context for me to figure out what you really want to do there, but I'm going to assume you want to do a string comparison.

Try this instead:

```
private void updateStatus(string some_program, Label label)
{
  if (some_program == "some string to compare with")
  { label.Text = "Completed"; }
  else
  { label.Text = "Failed"; }
}
```

And then you can call it by passing the `Label` right in:

```
updateStatus("file1", label2);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Hans said in the comments, make sure you are pass a label object as the argument to your method opposed to a string, so something like:

```
private void updateStatus(string some_program, Label label_number) {
```

If that does not fix the issue, please post the error message you're receiving.

Answer (score 0):

if you are passing first parameter as bool and second as string then Change your code like this :

```
private void updateStatus(bool some_program, string label_number)
{
    if (some_program == true)
    { label_number.Text = "Completed"; }
    else
    { label_number.Text = "Failed"; }
}
```

or

if you are passing first parameter as string and second as string then Change your code like this :

```
private void updateStatus(string some_program, string label_number)
{
    if (some_program == "What is your string value")
    { label_number.Text = "Completed"; }
    else
    { label_number.Text = "Failed"; }
}
```